# Referencing to Name Instead of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the following in my JS to catch the value of form control during submit, using the control's ID

```
var usernameInput = $("#usernameInput").val();
var passwordInput = $("#passwordInput").val();
```

if I need to use the control name (instead of ID), how can I reference it in my JS?

Edit : Please note that Im using an external JS file to catch the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is an attribute and you can use attributes to make a [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like this:

```
$('input[name="someName"]').val()
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery attribute selector like `$("input[attributeName='attributeValue']").val();`

```js
function getName() {
  var _n = $("input[name='newsletter']").val();
  console.log(_n)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="newsletter">
<button onclick="getName()">Get Value Using Name</button>
```